# Deploy application with Qt5 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, deb, qt5

I need to deploy my application which is depend on Qt5.x. No problem with that on 14.04+, but for 12.04 users there is seems to be no way to get qt5 from standard package repository. I'd like to pack my app to deb package and it won't be able to resolve qt dependency automatically(not using ppa).

The only solution I see is to built qt5 into my deb package and install it somewhere along with the application to user's system.

My questions is what is the most correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ppa to provide your application and add a dependency to include the qt5 packages available in the "Ubuntu SDK team" ppa.

You can easily add a ppa dependency to your own ppa using edit PPA dependencies:

[image]

The SDK ppa mentions this for 12.04:

> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has older versions of packages offered in this PPA,
>   but the SDK support has moved to the new 14.04 LTS release. It's
>   however **usable for example for general Qt 5 usage**.

Comment: "I'd like to pack my app to deb package and it won't be able to resolve qt dependency automatically(***not using ppa***)."

Comment: @Grammargeek: question was also "most correct way to achieve what I want". As explained you can express/resolve dependencies between ppas.